# Python: Naming of columns and merging two data frames into one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, optimization

I would like to give my sample data column names. I'd like the columns be named after objective functions and their decision variables like this: f_1, f_2, h, b, l, t

Sample data:

```
sampler = qmc.LatinHypercube(d=4)

u_bounds = np.array([5.0, 5.0, 10.0, 10.0])
l_bounds = np.array([0.125, 0.125, 0.1, 0.1])
data = sampler.lhs_method(100)*(u_bounds-(l_bounds)) + (l_bounds)
```

Optimisation problem where the column names come from:

```
def objectives (h,b,l,t):
    f1 = 1.10471*(h**2)*l + 0.04811*t*b*(14.0 + l)
    f2 = 2.1952 / (t**3)*b
    return f1,f2
```

Shaping the data for the objective functions:

```
y=np.zeros((100,2))   
for i in range(np.shape(data)[0]):
    y[i,0], y[i,1] = objectives(data[i,0], data[i,1], data[i,2], data[i,3])
```

What I tried:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df.columns = ["h", "b", "l", "t"]

df.head()

frames = [df, y,]

result = pd.concat(frames)
```

This errors like this: `TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'numpy.ndarray'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid`

So what kind of modifications would you recommend for this problem? Now it looks like these two data frames are not compatible in their current form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want them "side by side", you can do something like:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
df.columns = ["h", "b", "l", "t"]

# Adding new columns from variable y
df['f1'] = y[:,0]
df['f2'] = y[:,1]

# Quick check
df.head()
```

DataFrames represent tabular data. You can see them as a list of columns where each column has a name (f1, f2, h, b...) and can be accessed/modified through `my_dataframe['column_name']`.

Answer (score 1):

Like the error says, you can't `concat` a dataframe with a numpy array.

So you should transform y, the numpy array, into a df to concat with another df:

```
y = np.zeros((2,2)) 
y = pd.DataFrame(y) #this

pd.concat([df, y])
```

**Reproducing error:**

[image]

**Solving:**

[image]